# How can I get these divs to expand to full width inside an scrolling div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a file hierarchy in html/css and I can't get these labels or the divs they are in to expand to full width.  They only expand to the width of the visible area but I want the width of what they are in.  Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfzrczpp/) to see what I am talking about.  The grey area needs to all line up on the right.

```js
a = 3;
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div.hierarchy {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    width: 150px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

div.hierarchy label {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.directory {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
div.directory label {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hierarchy">
    <label>Hierarchy</label>
    <div class="directory">
        <label>src</label>
        <div class="directory">
            <div class="file"><label>test.txt</label></div>
            <div class="file"><label>readme.txt</label></div>
            <div class="file"><label>a really long filename.txt</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this bro : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mfzrczpp/1/)[link] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `div.directory` CSS class as follows:

```
div.directory {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

I made the following changes:

**1)** Added `display:inline-block;`

**2)** Removed the `width:100%;` rule.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nnd7jyj1/

(As a side note, it's **generally bad practice** in CSS to apply both a `width` and either a `padding` or `margin` rule to the same element. The reason for this is that some browsers interpret the `width` to include the `padding`/`margin` and some don't, which leads to inconsistent results)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I thought inline-block was to make things act like letters where you can define their width and height but they still flow inline like text.  But it seems more like block was doing this and inline-block is what makes them expand all the way like block does without scrolls... Anyways thank you :)

Comment: No problem, because you're using a fixed width container (with a scrollbar) it complicates the issue slightly since your blocks were extending 100% of the available width...which was 150px. You however you wanted the width to extend beyond 100% width. Using `display:inline-block` takes up the total remainder of the space, not only the `150px` specified on a parent `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `display:inline-block;` to `div.directory`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.hierarchy {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  width: 150px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div.hierarchy label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.directory {
  padding-left: 20px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* added */
  display: inline-block;
}
div.directory label {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hierarchy">
  <label>Hierarchy</label>
  <div class="directory">
    <label>src</label>
    <div class="directory">
      <div class="file">
        <label>test.txt</label>
      </div>
      <div class="file">
        <label>readme.txt</label>
      </div>
      <div class="file">
        <label>a really long filename.txt</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I chose the one below because he added the fiddle and everything.